# Play 2.4.x / java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Running my sbt build, I get the following unresolved dependencies.

This is what happens when I run sbt update or sbt eclipse:

```
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in:
com.typesafe.play:play-functional, com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor,  com.typesafe.play:play-json
, com.typesafe.play:play, com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees, com.typesafe.play:twirl-api, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j, org.scala-stm:scala-stm, com.ty
pesafe.play:play-datacommons
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/C:/test/}root:
[error]    com.typesafe.play:play-functional _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.play:play-json _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.play:play _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.play:twirl-api _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.play:play-datacommons _2.11, _2.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.typesafe.play:play-functional, com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor, com.typesafe.play:
play-json, com.typesafe.play:play, com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees, com.typesafe.play:twirl-api, com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j, org.scala-stm:scala-st
m, com.typesafe.play:play-datacommons
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:46)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:32)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$66.apply(Defaults.scala:1164)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$66.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My build.sbt has the following:

```
name := "TestWeb"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)

EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java 
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources) 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.julienrf" % "play-jsmessages_2.10" % "2.0.0"
)

fork in run := true
```

My project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
```

And sbt.version=0.13.8

I can't add JsMessages plugin...

Comment: Just so you know: [Java and JavaScript are very different.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Comment: Yes, I have to add translations (i18n) for Java and JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Scala **2.11**, you need to use appropriate dependency, not **2.10**. This change should help you.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.julienrf" % "play-jsmessages_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `2.10` in `play-jsmessages_2.10` stands for Scala 2.10. Scala binary compatibility issues (too much to get into here) means that many libraries have Scala-version-specific dependency versions. sbt is trying to tell you that you have both `2.11` and `2.10` dependencies.

If you're using Scala 2.11.6, you'll want a `jsmessages` dependency that is compatible with it.